# MvvmCross Dynamic ListView with Groups

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing an app for Android using Xamarin & MvvmCross. A simple version of View Models might look something like this:

```
public abstract class PersonViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ICanRemove
{
    MvxCommand RemoveCommand { get; }
}

public class LonelyPersonViewModel : PersonViewModelBase, ICanRemove
{
    public bool IsHappy { get; set; }

    public MvxCommand RemoveCommand { get { return new MvxCommand(() => RemoveFriend())); } }

    private void RemoveFriend()
    {
        // Sends msg to remove a friend (using IMvxMessenger)
    }
}

public class TiredPersonViewModel : PersonViewModelBase, ICanRemove
{
    public int HoursSleepNeeded { get; set; }

    // [ICanRemove implementation]
}

public class FriendlyPersonViewModel : PersonViewModelBase
{

    public List<PersonViewModelBase> Friends { get; set; }

    public MvxCommand AddFieldCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(
                () => AddFriend());
        }
    }

    private void AddFriend()
    {

    }
}

public class FriendsViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Friends.Add(new LonelyPersonViewModel { Name = "Friend 1" });
        Friends.Add(new TiredPersonViewModel { Name = "Friend 2" });

        var friend3 = new FriendlyPersonViewModel { Name = "Friend 3" };
        friend3.Friends.Add(new LonelyPersonViewModel { Name = "SubFriend 1" });
        friend3.Friends.Add(new TiredPersonViewModel { Name = "SubFriend 2" });
        Friends.Add(friend3);

        Friends.Add(new LonelyPersonViewModel { Name = "Friend 4" });

        var friend5 = new FriendlyPersonViewModel { Name = "Friend 5" };
        var conjoinedFriend1 = new ConjoinedPersonViewModel { Name = "MultiPerson 1" };
        conjoinedFriend1.CoPeople.Add(new TiredPersonViewModel { Name = "Jim" });
        conjoinedFriend1.CoPeople.Add(new LonelyPersonViewModel { Name = "Nancy" });
        friend5.Friends.Add(conjoinedFriend1);
        Friends.Add(friend5);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModelBase> Friends { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModelBase>();
}
```

The Friends view will be a ListView that displays the Friends as either a flat item or another list of friends. So it could look like this:

- Friend 1
- Friend 2
- Friend 3 [Add]

  - SubFriend 1 [Del]
  - SubFriend 2 [Del]
- Friend 4
- Friend 5 [Add]

  - MultiPerson 1 [Del]

    - Jim
    - Nancy

The [Add] and [Del] are buttons that bind to the Add/Delete commands on the ViewModels. Currently, I'm using the CustomAdapter from the PolymorphicListView example, so each ViewModel is mapped to a custom layout. However, I don't currently have the full info displaying for FriendlyPersonViewModel or ConjoinedPersonViewModel.

I'm torn on how to continue:

1. I looked into doing nested listviews and found that it's not a good UX and I didn't go down through actually connecting the custom adapter to the child listviews.
2. I started the work to flatten the lists manually and having the Friends collection in the FriendsListView handle the Add/Remove. However, I need the subfriends to show up under the proper friend and they are currently just showing up at the bottom of the list, which is not idea, as the actual ViewModels are slightly more complex and would cause quite a bit of redundancy due to the FriendlyPeople names being repeated for each Friend added.
3. I looked at the old GroupedListView example from the Conference example, but each friend won't actually be in a group, some will be displayed alone.

Below is how I've got my current app working so far. The first Dark Blue section with the "Add" button was used to add the later dark blue sections; same for the Green sections. As I mentioned above, I'd like to have the later Dark Blue sections show up with the first Dark Blue section when I hit Add. I'd like for the first blue/green section to essentially be a header and have the next blue/green section directly below it; then hit add and have the next proper color show up under the right section without another header.

[image: Current App]

Does anyone have any suggestions or guidance on how to achieve this with Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross?

Thanks!
 -g

Afterthought: It looks like there is an InsertItem on ObservableCollection, if I find the location of the last item added for the secrion I want to add the next PersonBase to, will the UI update properly? (Already left desk, or I'd check.)

**UPDATE**

Simply inserting the item using Insert(idx,item) will in fact update the UI properly and display the new item in the correct location. The next step would be, how do you style the items such that they are obviously a "group"?

Comment: Do you mean to style them depending on which item type they are? Like having a different style for a category item? Then maybe look at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/pull/200

Comment: A quick look at the link makes me think it *might* work. I'll have to try it and see.


I'd like to style the related "Friends" like they are in a group. So the Friend as sort of a header, then the list of friends under him/her in a way that they are obviously related to the above Friend.

However, not all Friends will have lists, so I'm not sure the way Stuart did the Conference exampled with the GroupedListView will work in this scenario (at least not exactly).

Comment: Basically you set the prefered display style over a enum in your models and with a multitemplateselector the recyclerview should pick the right one to display it. Though the sorting you would have to do it yourself. 
I as an example had categories with a expanded flag, if set to true i would add the items, else remove them. Categories had a own style there and the items themself too. Maybe i will find time to do a example for that, though iam kinda trying to fix a current bug myself.